# Mouse Right Click on WindowsUI DevExpress

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Actually, I am have designed an application using `WindowsUI`(`MetroUI`) with `TileContainers`.

Now,My problem is that : I have a text in `TextBox` and I have selected the text and want to copy it with `mouse right click` other than `ctrl+c`.(Because my clients are not aware of the shortcuts).

So,When I'm `rightclicking` on the textbox with `mouse`,the `TileContainer` `WindowsUIButtons` are sliding from top of the page.

Is there any chance of getting that?
sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then you could just use a Context Menu.
See [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/contextmenustrip) URL for a step by step process on doing exactly what it sounds like you are wanting.

[image]

Hope this helps.